# CMAKE find_package successful, but TARGET not found

Tags: cmake, package, target, find-package

In my CMakeLists.txt file I’m trying to build “Bob”, which is a library that gets linked to later. The `find_package` request is successful, but the `"if(NOT TARGET..."` check fails. I figured if Bob was found then Bob::Bob would also be found. I could obviously be wrong.

What is `“if(NOT TARGET Bob::Bob)”` using to determine **true** or **false**? How do I set it up correctly?

*CMakeLists.txt:*

```
find_package(Bob ${BOB_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})


if (${Bob_FOUND})
    message(STATUS "Found Bob")
else (${Bob_FOUND})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not locate Bob! Abort!")
endif (${Bob_FOUND})


if(NOT TARGET Bob::Bob)
    message(WARNING "Cannot build without Bob::Bob!”)
...
```

*Output:*

```
#13 3.210 Finding Bob...
#13 3.210
#13 3.210 Entered BobConfigVersion.cmake
#13 3.210 Value of BOB_VERSION is: 2022.12.01
#13 3.210    PACKAGE_VERSION           : 2022.12.01
#13 3.210    Bob_VERSION          : 2022.12.01
#13 3.210    PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION      : 2022.12.01
#13 3.210    PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE: TRUE
#13 3.210    PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT     : TRUE
#13 3.210 Exiting BobConfigVersion.cmake

#13 3.213 -- Found Bob
#13 3.320   Cannot build without Bob::Bob!
```

Comment: Actually, `find_package(Bob)` just executes corresponding `BobConfig.cmake` script. It is up to that script to create a target, to define variables or to do something else. If you wonder how to write such script, then see [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages).

Comment: It would be better if you'd tell us the exact library name instead of using `Bob`.

Comment: I've looked at the CMake documentation, but nothing I've found answers the question: What is “if(NOT TARGET Bob::Bob)” using to determine true or false?